# JBoss 5.1.0 + EJB 3.1 + JMS

Tags: java, jms, jboss5.x, ejb-3.1

Can somebody advice me what I need to do in jboss to deploy message driven bean. In particular I am looking answers on following questions:

1. Do I need to define jms topic, connection factory etc... in config files, if yes where and how
2. Where I will specify a url to remote JMS server

Any helpful links or code snippets really appreciated

UPDATE#1: Maybe I explained myself not very well, my clarification is about architecture. I have external JMS server which is deployed on separate machine and I want to create EJB3 MDR Bean to receive messages from particular topc. I know all properties like host, port, username and password, and I am able to send and receive messages via JMS api. What I want to do is to create and configure properly MDR Bean on top of jboss, but I am not sure where to put all these configuration like host, port, username, password etc...

Comment: Have you googled for this? http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/configuring-jms-in-jboss-5/

Comment: Sure, but what is confusing for me, it is where I need specify the url to remote server

Comment: I think I didn't explained myself very well, please see my update

Comment: @endryha - Please see my answer there are two options where to put that information. The first is in Annotations on the MDB class and the other is in the MDB's deployment descriptor. I attached to my answer a link the JBoss Community Wiki with an Example MDB for the JBoss 5 container. Specifically look at the     @Resource(mappedName="jnp://localhost:1100/queue/test"); annotation

Answer (score 0):

Your Message Driven Bean itself will be deployed into the container using a standard EJB Spec compliant deployment descriptor or annotations on the MDB itself.

Here is an [example](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EJB3MessageDrivenBean) from the JBoss Community Wiki. Its a little complex as it has a bunch of extra things in it including transaction support, injection of session beans, etc. But it demonstrates how to create an EJB3 MDB from annotations. It may be worth playing with just to see what you can omit. You may also need to play with it a bit just to get it to work(for instance you may not have a bean for IMySessionBean - so perhaps you will just get rid of this entirely and replace with a println() or something to get yourself started)

As for your message producer If its standalone java app the url's etc. will be supplied through the properties supplied to your JNDI InitialContext when creating your ConnectionFactory. This is demonstrated in this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2EE/ThisexampleisasimpleJMSclientapplication.htm)

If you are in the container, refer to the first example above which also provides an example using the JMSXA connection factory(a special connection factory specific to the container that has addtional features related to JCA- connection pooling, etc.).

Comment: Can you show me how you specify url to remote jms server? Or better just show me your config

Comment: They are in the links. I need to know what you are trying to do. Please post your MDB and your client code.